# how can I print gcc default alignment number?

Tags: c, gcc, memory

I just want to know the alignment number of my machine, is there any command to print the GCC's alignment number?

actually, I just want to check the default number of GCC's #pragma pack(), is there any command I get it?

Comment: Alignment could depend on type. For example a 32-bit `int` will typically have different alignment requirements than a single-byte `char`.

Comment: You could use `_Alignof`, but as @Someprogrammerdude said, alignment is different for types, so for `int` you could see `_Alignof(int)`, for `char` `_Alignof(char)`, etc. Note that if you include `<stdalign.h>`, you can use `alignof` instead of `_Alignof`.